# How to create a chart from the big table in latex?

Tags: graphics, charts

[data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8LOi4c1D8iBcTk4cDBJWDI1NEU/view?usp=sharing)

I need help with data visualusation in latex. I have imported excel file (attached) to `.csv` and `.tex` formats, however, I still to not know how to create a chart like in Excel directly in latex.

Here is the table in `.tex` format also

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering

\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllll}
t    & Germany & Netherlands & USA     & Italy  & Russian Federation & Sweden & Canada & Spain  & UK     & France \\
1970 & 1038774 & 48615       & 388728  & 149646 & .                  & 77654  & 128625 & 40395  & 98372  & 18784  \\
1971 & 931120  & 50428       & 393140  & 150910 & .                  & 42961  & 102470 & 45169  & 97482  & 20614  \\
1972 & 846068  & 45363       & 414878  & 141195 & .                  & 30227  & 100549 & 47027  & 95187  & 23067  \\
1973 & 927168  & 48540       & 432858  & 133888 & .                  & 29793  & 145598 & 49609  & 104462 & 23715  \\
1974 & 594759  & 49233       & 426078  & 131439 & .                  & 37883  & 218129 & 57883  & 97737  & 23018  \\
1975 & 424798  & 56404       & 419461  & 115143 & .                  & 44544  & 191365 & 48991  & 93107  & 21824  \\
1976 & 470500  & 51452       & 530009  & 95799  & .                  & 45474  & 151717 & 41654  & 92549  & 21814  \\
1977 & 516596  & 51829       & 492868  & 85283  & .                  & 43875  & 116865 & 32615  & 86791  & 19603  \\
1978 & 552701  & 57885       & 637592  & 85125  & .                  & 36134  & 92047  & 24537  & 103074 & 20992  \\
1979 & 638904  & 72233       & 497309  & 85267  & .                  & 36961  & 120693 & 18492  & 93382  & 20255  \\
1980 & 729711  & 82035       & 576637  & 91783  & 1121               & 38903  & 149134 & 17671  & 102461 & 24988  \\
1981 & 608946  & 53959       & 639557  & 132417 & 1091               & 32723  & 136359 & 15733  & 92211  & 24844  \\
1982 & 408438  & 45109       & 644028  & 107726 & 1050               & 27353  & 126515 & 17984  & 105813 & 25113  \\
1983 & 357250  & 42248       & 610554  & 97403  & 989                & 27536  & 94175  & 26486  & 112248 & 23027  \\
1984 & 413333  & 42394       & 594661  & 83915  & 1002               & 31883  & 93052  & 25206  & 108552 & 21622  \\
1985 & 480573  & 66535       & 617008  & 77783  & 1016               & 33667  & 90763  & 24152  & 185646 & 21561  \\
1986 & 544441  & 72242       & 660790  & 72871  & 1097               & 39908  & 109418 & 18378  & 200979 & 25391  \\
1987 & 598662  & 88322       & 667939  & 69251  & 2454               & 43448  & 163081 & 21879  & 194430 & 24709  \\
1988 & 901088  & 82520       & 702081  & 78464  & 5435               & 51631  & 172144 & 28273  & 213084 & 23989  \\
1989 & 1543249 & 90694       & 1148684 & 81993  & 11478              & 66799  & 199925 & 36828  & 257118 & 28279  \\
1990 & 1616933 & 108648      & 1599146 & 134794 & 52468              & 59498  & 224577 & 36791  & 247424 & 30199  \\
1991 & 1164808 & 111755      & 1901288 & 97321  & 692198             & 48748  & 245679 & 28109  & 228662 & 37995  \\
1992 & 1394251 & 107814      & 1024015 & 85939  & 935540             & 45751  & 258017 & 43309  & 174863 & 36563  \\
1993 & 1187744 & 114277      & 953961  & 84374  & 944921             & 62391  & 260507 & 38089  & 172925 & 36414  \\
1994 & 940089  & 83633       & 849536  & 82412  & 1145955            & 83851  & 228258 & 40155  & 214416 & 131244 \\
1995 & 1024438 & 91037       & 777842  & 107657 & 817391             & 47063  & 215966 & 42042  & 206314 & 116837 \\
1996 & 896452  & 102768      & 965663  & 184223 & 612795             & 41081  & 230679 & 37205  & 220745 & 118047 \\
1997 & 784344  & 102983      & 865416  & 176066 & 587430             & 45852  & 221547 & 63281  & 233506 & 139956 \\
1998 & 760613  & 112908      & 742660  & 182169 & 503186             & 51082  & 181049 & 88567  & 309623 & 173075 \\
1999 & 778584  & 108380      & 734723  & 202127 & 377722             & 51192  & 195585 & 132186 & 324717 & 170346 \\
2000 & 741297  & 115541      & 903504  & 229859 & 342273             & 58005  & 232895 & 371946 & 334844 & 174596 \\
2001 & 723275  & 119799      & 1087605 & 214668 & 254682             & 60461  & 256053 & 402962 & 356642 & 193441 \\
2002 & 728390  & 111794      & 1092260 & 223754 & 233716             & 62195  & 237817 & 459754 & 366457 & 226413 \\
2003 & 523035  & 93183       & 755742  & 434219 & 171349             & 61225  & 224545 & 440954 & 400840 & 240711 \\
2004 & 613940  & 83478       & 984772  & 411620 & 153969             & 59987  & 241880 & 502212 & 463530 & 229882 \\
2005 & 566328  & 82971       & 1127825 & 303856 & 189290             & 61861  & 269471 & 554646 & 442372 & 233983 \\
2006 & 514522  & 89291       & 1283288 & 276017 & 187945             & 90510  & 261060 & 643204 & 392609 & 199265 \\
2007 & 535727  & 100131      & 1076560 & 408556 & 275126             & 93328  & 241939 & 728072 & 198742 & 163205 \\
2008 & 557024  & 123939      & 1139351 & 444747 & 262628             & 94955  & 257286 & 556450 & 343840 & 60423  \\
2009 & 73144   & 115278      & 1106166 & 390892 & 217597             & 95523  & 246479 & 352814 & 369137 & 61581  \\
2010 & 91851   & 118737      & 1042438 & 461404 & 193131             & 95755  & 278331 & 345155 & 435204 & 75859  \\
2011 & 93304   & 122318      & 1077760 & 385429 & 8691               & 90341  & 251931 & 352893 & 408161 & 76669  \\
2012 & 109891  & 114734      & 1052898 & 349690 & 10540              & 96685  & 266496 & 284632 & 336541 & 86158  \\
2013 & 97563   & 120610      & 1013967 & 310523 & 12324              & 108568 & 267463 & 266347 & 294307 & 77634 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! About chart, please be more specific what kind of chart you like to have. The package `pgfplots` is intended for such tasks. See it manual http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf and also see examples http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `siunitx` for pretty printing the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}

\sisetup{group-four-digits}
\scriptsize\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-3pt}
%\footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.1pt}
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  c
  S[table-format=7.0]%GE
  S[table-format=6.0]%NL
  S[table-format=7.0]%US
  S[table-format=6.0]%IT
  S[table-format=7.0]%RU
  S[table-format=6.0]%SE
  S[table-format=6.0]%CA
  S[table-format=6.0]%SP
  S[table-format=6.0]%UK
  S[table-format=6.0]%FR
  @{}
}
\toprule
Year  & {DE} & {NL} & {US} & {IT} & {RU} & {SE} & {CA} & {SP} & {UK} & {FR} \\
\midrule
1970 & 1038774 & 48615    & 388728  & 149646 & {---}      & 77654  & 128625 & 40395  & 98372  & 18784  \\
1971 & 931120  & 50428    & 393140  & 150910 & {---}      & 42961  & 102470 & 45169  & 97482  & 20614  \\
1972 & 846068  & 45363    & 414878  & 141195 & {---}      & 30227  & 100549 & 47027  & 95187  & 23067  \\
1973 & 927168  & 48540    & 432858  & 133888 & {---}      & 29793  & 145598 & 49609  & 104462 & 23715  \\
1974 & 594759  & 49233    & 426078  & 131439 & {---}      & 37883  & 218129 & 57883  & 97737  & 23018  \\
1975 & 424798  & 56404    & 419461  & 115143 & {---}      & 44544  & 191365 & 48991  & 93107  & 21824  \\
1976 & 470500  & 51452    & 530009  & 95799  & {---}      & 45474  & 151717 & 41654  & 92549  & 21814  \\
1977 & 516596  & 51829    & 492868  & 85283  & {---}      & 43875  & 116865 & 32615  & 86791  & 19603  \\
1978 & 552701  & 57885    & 637592  & 85125  & {---}      & 36134  & 92047  & 24537  & 103074 & 20992  \\
1979 & 638904  & 72233    & 497309  & 85267  & {---}      & 36961  & 120693 & 18492  & 93382  & 20255  \\
\addlinespace
1980 & 729711  & 82035    & 576637  & 91783  & 1121      & 38903  & 149134 & 17671  & 102461 & 24988  \\
1981 & 608946  & 53959    & 639557  & 132417 & 1091      & 32723  & 136359 & 15733  & 92211  & 24844  \\
1982 & 408438  & 45109    & 644028  & 107726 & 1050      & 27353  & 126515 & 17984  & 105813 & 25113  \\
1983 & 357250  & 42248    & 610554  & 97403  & 989    & 27536  & 94175  & 26486  & 112248 & 23027  \\
1984 & 413333  & 42394    & 594661  & 83915  & 1002      & 31883  & 93052  & 25206  & 108552 & 21622  \\
1985 & 480573  & 66535    & 617008  & 77783  & 1016      & 33667  & 90763  & 24152  & 185646 & 21561  \\
1986 & 544441  & 72242    & 660790  & 72871  & 1097      & 39908  & 109418 & 18378  & 200979 & 25391  \\
1987 & 598662  & 88322    & 667939  & 69251  & 2454      & 43448  & 163081 & 21879  & 194430 & 24709  \\
1988 & 901088  & 82520    & 702081  & 78464  & 5435      & 51631  & 172144 & 28273  & 213084 & 23989  \\
1989 & 1543249 & 90694    & 1148684 & 81993  & 11478     & 66799  & 199925 & 36828  & 257118 & 28279  \\
\addlinespace
1990 & 1616933 & 108648   & 1599146 & 134794 & 52468     & 59498  & 224577 & 36791  & 247424 & 30199  \\
1991 & 1164808 & 111755   & 1901288 & 97321  & 692198    & 48748  & 245679 & 28109  & 228662 & 37995  \\
1992 & 1394251 & 107814   & 1024015 & 85939  & 935540    & 45751  & 258017 & 43309  & 174863 & 36563  \\
1993 & 1187744 & 114277   & 953961  & 84374  & 944921    & 62391  & 260507 & 38089  & 172925 & 36414  \\
1994 & 940089  & 83633    & 849536  & 82412  & 1145955   & 83851  & 228258 & 40155  & 214416 & 131244 \\
1995 & 1024438 & 91037    & 777842  & 107657 & 817391    & 47063  & 215966 & 42042  & 206314 & 116837 \\
1996 & 896452  & 102768   & 965663  & 184223 & 612795    & 41081  & 230679 & 37205  & 220745 & 118047 \\
1997 & 784344  & 102983   & 865416  & 176066 & 587430    & 45852  & 221547 & 63281  & 233506 & 139956 \\
1998 & 760613  & 112908   & 742660  & 182169 & 503186    & 51082  & 181049 & 88567  & 309623 & 173075 \\
1999 & 778584  & 108380   & 734723  & 202127 & 377722    & 51192  & 195585 & 132186 & 324717 & 170346 \\
\addlinespace
2000 & 741297  & 115541   & 903504  & 229859 & 342273    & 58005  & 232895 & 371946 & 334844 & 174596 \\
2001 & 723275  & 119799   & 1087605 & 214668 & 254682    & 60461  & 256053 & 402962 & 356642 & 193441 \\
2002 & 728390  & 111794   & 1092260 & 223754 & 233716    & 62195  & 237817 & 459754 & 366457 & 226413 \\
2003 & 523035  & 93183    & 755742  & 434219 & 171349    & 61225  & 224545 & 440954 & 400840 & 240711 \\
2004 & 613940  & 83478    & 984772  & 411620 & 153969    & 59987  & 241880 & 502212 & 463530 & 229882 \\
2005 & 566328  & 82971    & 1127825 & 303856 & 189290    & 61861  & 269471 & 554646 & 442372 & 233983 \\
2006 & 514522  & 89291    & 1283288 & 276017 & 187945    & 90510  & 261060 & 643204 & 392609 & 199265 \\
2007 & 535727  & 100131   & 1076560 & 408556 & 275126    & 93328  & 241939 & 728072 & 198742 & 163205 \\
2008 & 557024  & 123939   & 1139351 & 444747 & 262628    & 94955  & 257286 & 556450 & 343840 & 60423  \\
2009 & 73144   & 115278   & 1106166 & 390892 & 217597    & 95523  & 246479 & 352814 & 369137 & 61581  \\
\addlinespace
2010 & 91851   & 118737   & 1042438 & 461404 & 193131    & 95755  & 278331 & 345155 & 435204 & 75859  \\
2011 & 93304   & 122318   & 1077760 & 385429 & 8691      & 90341  & 251931 & 352893 & 408161 & 76669  \\
2012 & 109891  & 114734   & 1052898 & 349690 & 10540     & 96685  & 266496 & 284632 & 336541 & 86158  \\
2013 & 97563   & 120610   & 1013967 & 310523 & 12324     & 108568 & 267463 & 266347 & 294307 & 77634\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Getting this to fit the standard page size requires either using `\scriptsize` and reducing by 3pt the column separations; in `\footnotesize` it comes out too tight. Experiment with your own page width.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume your query is about how to provide some extra visual cues such as lines that set off the header from the body of text. If this assumption is correct, the following code may be relevant to you. The solution deliberately uses no vertical lines and very few horizontal lines. The numbers in the data columns are right-aligned. For visual appeal, there's slightly more interline whitespace after every tenth year. Finally, I chose to use two-letter acronyms for the country names; without this device, some of the columns would be excessively wide and the table wouldn't fit in the page block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set text block parameters
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{My caption} \label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{r} @{}}
\toprule
Year  & \mc{GE} & \mc{NL} & \mc{US} & \mc{IT} & \mc{RU} & \mc{SE} & \mc{CA} & \mc{SP} & \mc{UK} & \mc{FR} \\
\midrule
1970 & 1038774 & 48615       & 388728  & 149646 & .                  & 77654  & 128625 & 40395  & 98372  & 18784  \\
1971 & 931120  & 50428       & 393140  & 150910 & .                  & 42961  & 102470 & 45169  & 97482  & 20614  \\
1972 & 846068  & 45363       & 414878  & 141195 & .                  & 30227  & 100549 & 47027  & 95187  & 23067  \\
1973 & 927168  & 48540       & 432858  & 133888 & .                  & 29793  & 145598 & 49609  & 104462 & 23715  \\
1974 & 594759  & 49233       & 426078  & 131439 & .                  & 37883  & 218129 & 57883  & 97737  & 23018  \\
1975 & 424798  & 56404       & 419461  & 115143 & .                  & 44544  & 191365 & 48991  & 93107  & 21824  \\
1976 & 470500  & 51452       & 530009  & 95799  & .                  & 45474  & 151717 & 41654  & 92549  & 21814  \\
1977 & 516596  & 51829       & 492868  & 85283  & .                  & 43875  & 116865 & 32615  & 86791  & 19603  \\
1978 & 552701  & 57885       & 637592  & 85125  & .                  & 36134  & 92047  & 24537  & 103074 & 20992  \\
1979 & 638904  & 72233       & 497309  & 85267  & .                  & 36961  & 120693 & 18492  & 93382  & 20255  \\
\addlinespace
1980 & 729711  & 82035       & 576637  & 91783  & 1121               & 38903  & 149134 & 17671  & 102461 & 24988  \\
1981 & 608946  & 53959       & 639557  & 132417 & 1091               & 32723  & 136359 & 15733  & 92211  & 24844  \\
1982 & 408438  & 45109       & 644028  & 107726 & 1050               & 27353  & 126515 & 17984  & 105813 & 25113  \\
1983 & 357250  & 42248       & 610554  & 97403  & 989                & 27536  & 94175  & 26486  & 112248 & 23027  \\
1984 & 413333  & 42394       & 594661  & 83915  & 1002               & 31883  & 93052  & 25206  & 108552 & 21622  \\
1985 & 480573  & 66535       & 617008  & 77783  & 1016               & 33667  & 90763  & 24152  & 185646 & 21561  \\
1986 & 544441  & 72242       & 660790  & 72871  & 1097               & 39908  & 109418 & 18378  & 200979 & 25391  \\
1987 & 598662  & 88322       & 667939  & 69251  & 2454               & 43448  & 163081 & 21879  & 194430 & 24709  \\
1988 & 901088  & 82520       & 702081  & 78464  & 5435               & 51631  & 172144 & 28273  & 213084 & 23989  \\
1989 & 1543249 & 90694       & 1148684 & 81993  & 11478              & 66799  & 199925 & 36828  & 257118 & 28279  \\
\addlinespace
1990 & 1616933 & 108648      & 1599146 & 134794 & 52468              & 59498  & 224577 & 36791  & 247424 & 30199  \\
1991 & 1164808 & 111755      & 1901288 & 97321  & 692198             & 48748  & 245679 & 28109  & 228662 & 37995  \\
1992 & 1394251 & 107814      & 1024015 & 85939  & 935540             & 45751  & 258017 & 43309  & 174863 & 36563  \\
1993 & 1187744 & 114277      & 953961  & 84374  & 944921             & 62391  & 260507 & 38089  & 172925 & 36414  \\
1994 & 940089  & 83633       & 849536  & 82412  & 1145955            & 83851  & 228258 & 40155  & 214416 & 131244 \\
1995 & 1024438 & 91037       & 777842  & 107657 & 817391             & 47063  & 215966 & 42042  & 206314 & 116837 \\
1996 & 896452  & 102768      & 965663  & 184223 & 612795             & 41081  & 230679 & 37205  & 220745 & 118047 \\
1997 & 784344  & 102983      & 865416  & 176066 & 587430             & 45852  & 221547 & 63281  & 233506 & 139956 \\
1998 & 760613  & 112908      & 742660  & 182169 & 503186             & 51082  & 181049 & 88567  & 309623 & 173075 \\
1999 & 778584  & 108380      & 734723  & 202127 & 377722             & 51192  & 195585 & 132186 & 324717 & 170346 \\
\addlinespace
2000 & 741297  & 115541      & 903504  & 229859 & 342273             & 58005  & 232895 & 371946 & 334844 & 174596 \\
2001 & 723275  & 119799      & 1087605 & 214668 & 254682             & 60461  & 256053 & 402962 & 356642 & 193441 \\
2002 & 728390  & 111794      & 1092260 & 223754 & 233716             & 62195  & 237817 & 459754 & 366457 & 226413 \\
2003 & 523035  & 93183       & 755742  & 434219 & 171349             & 61225  & 224545 & 440954 & 400840 & 240711 \\
2004 & 613940  & 83478       & 984772  & 411620 & 153969             & 59987  & 241880 & 502212 & 463530 & 229882 \\
2005 & 566328  & 82971       & 1127825 & 303856 & 189290             & 61861  & 269471 & 554646 & 442372 & 233983 \\
2006 & 514522  & 89291       & 1283288 & 276017 & 187945             & 90510  & 261060 & 643204 & 392609 & 199265 \\
2007 & 535727  & 100131      & 1076560 & 408556 & 275126             & 93328  & 241939 & 728072 & 198742 & 163205 \\
2008 & 557024  & 123939      & 1139351 & 444747 & 262628             & 94955  & 257286 & 556450 & 343840 & 60423  \\
2009 & 73144   & 115278      & 1106166 & 390892 & 217597             & 95523  & 246479 & 352814 & 369137 & 61581  \\
\addlinespace
2010 & 91851   & 118737      & 1042438 & 461404 & 193131             & 95755  & 278331 & 345155 & 435204 & 75859  \\
2011 & 93304   & 122318      & 1077760 & 385429 & 8691               & 90341  & 251931 & 352893 & 408161 & 76669  \\
2012 & 109891  & 114734      & 1052898 & 349690 & 10540              & 96685  & 266496 & 284632 & 336541 & 86158  \\
2013 & 97563   & 120610      & 1013967 & 310523 & 12324              & 108568 & 267463 & 266347 & 294307 & 77634\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```